# Application installed on the phone looks different

Tags: ios, xcode

The application works perfectly in
[Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G7yX.jpg).
But when I installed on my phone it looks like that: [on phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blljG.jpg),

The separator from table view is moved to the right side, the custom segmented control also is moved a little bit to the right side.

How to solve the problem? On the phone to looks exactly like in simulator

Comment: Hi, I've noticed that in the "on the phone" screenshot it says "iPod" and font sizes a different, which leads me to guess that simulator emulates a different device than the actual device you run the app on. As a first step, I would try to use the same device in simulator (it seems to be smaller, so, perhaps, it's iPhone 5 form factor).

Comment: Ok, but there's no difference between the iPhone 5 and my current iPod 5 Touch

Comment: I see. My point is, simulator is emulating a different device from the one you are using. In order to spot and correct the issues, it would be useful to find a simulated device that gives similar results. Generally speaking, something seems to be wrong with layout in your app, however, there are too many possibilities to consider and more information is necessary even for an educated guess.